# Can I buy season 2 of The Walking Dead one game episode at a time?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-two

I want to buy The Walking Dead Season 2 game episodes one at a time, and not have to buy them all on one disk, at one time. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: on what platform?

Comment: oh sorry, ps3 or pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can purchase the episodes individually from the PlayStation Network store as they are released for PS3, for example [episode 1 is found here on the EU store](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-gb/games/the-walking-dead-season-2-ep1-all-that-remains/cid=EP2026-NPEB01911_00-TWDS200000000KEY?gclid=CLiA-sH9l78CFVIPtAodbygAow). The store offers a search facility to find it, and the other episodes.

I don't think it is possible to buy the episodes individually for the PC.

Answer (score 0):

For purchasing on windows, or OSx you may purchase the "Season Pass" from [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/news/12121/)

```
The Season Pass gives you access to all five episodes as they become available (Episode 1 Available Now, Episodes 2-5 will be released periodically in 2014):

Episode 1: All That Remains
Episode 2: A House Divided
Episode 3: In Harm’s Way
Episode 4: Amid the Ruins
Episode 5: No Going Back
```

There is no other method of buying individual episodes